# Java: question about method invokation in for loops

Tags: java

I have a for loop with the following lines:

```
method1(similarities.instance(i));
method2(similarities.instance(i));
method3(similarities.instance(i));
```

If I store into a variable a = similarities.instance(i) and I change the for loop with:

```
method1(a);
method2(a);
method3(a)
```

;

do I get much better performances ? Because I'm not invoking the method at each iteration ? Is it something i should always do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should store it, this will ensure no worth preformance, and also will not fail if `similarites.instacnce()` has side effects you don't want to repeat

Answer (score 2):

if similarities.instance(i) is equal to similarities.instance(i) for all invocation, your second approach is appropriate, and yes, you will get the better performance.

**Updated(Based on [Ingo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/86604/ingo) comment):** 
And, in addition, the result must not be modified by any of the consumer methods

Comment: And, in addition, the result must not be modified by any of the consumer methods

Comment: This seems to just say its okay to do the second thing and not answer his question at all?

Answer (score 0):

This depends mostly on what's inside `similarities.instance()`. Below I assume that the 3 calls are perfectly identical.

If it's a plain simple getter, you most probably won't notice any performance difference either way. If it's resource-heavy, you may. Even then, though, I believe the JIT could easily optimize away the 3 distinct method calls, storing the result in a temporary. Bottom line is, you shouldn't worry about micro-optimization.

So in most of the cases, the only difference would be readability (which is important enough in itself). From this perspective, I would prefer option 2.

Comment: Hardly. This would mean that the JIT can solve the halting problem.

Answer (score 0):

Like so many things it depends.  If similarities.instance(i) is expensive to call then storing it in a variable and reusing it will make a difference in performance.

This is really not a question that can be answered in the general however. You need to profile/test the difference in performance to see if it makes a difference.  I would say in most cases you shouldn't worry about it unless the method call is doing something slow like hitting a database or the network.

That said I would change it to the variable anyway to cut down on duplication.

Answer (score 0):

This is safe to do if both of the following are true:

1. similarities.instance() is a pure function
2. method1, method2, method3 use their parameter read only.

Answer (score 0):

By assigning that instance to a variable, you store in memory the physical address of that instance as a pointer.

By accessing every time that instance passing from the similarities object, you reach it passing each time through the memory address of the `similarities` object, that somewhere and somehow stores in a memory structure the address of the instance you want to reach.

So yes, it definitely improves performances, although i'm not 100% sure if the JVM make some optimization itself. But i would say no.

Answer (score 0):

"Premature optimization is the root of all evil" (c)Donald Knuth

Does this code really bootle neck? Did you do profiling or some tests for determining this?

In common case I see only one reason to store value of method invocation - better readability. Of cause value must be permanent and independent from invocation time.
I mean this:

```
int a = someObj.getSomething();
method1( a );
method2( a );
method3( a );
```

This code is not good:

```
int length = someObj.getLength();
for( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
{
...
}
```

And sometimes behavior could be opposite to your expectation.

Comment: The code you say is "not good" is just fine as long as the length doesn't change in the loop.

Comment: It works in this case but it doesn't make sense to use such "optimization". Code becomes more confused without any profit.